# how to calculate the odds of 5d6 higher than 1d10?

Tags: statistics, anydice

In anydice or troll, how can we calculate the odds of rolling 5d6 and counting the successes against 1d10?
Successes are every result in each six-sided die **equal or higher** than the **d10** result.

This means that, if the d10 rolls 7, 8, 9, or 10, you always have zero successes, and if it rolls a 1, you always have 5.

I've tried `[count {1..d10} in 5d6]`, but anydice says sequence must end with a number. I've tried `5d6>1d10`, but obviously anydice takes 5d6 as the sum of the dice. Maybe it can be done with a custom function, but that seems beyond my skills...

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you need any guidance about posting questions and answers! How do you count when the 1d10 and one 1d6 roll are equal? Success or failure?

Answer (score 6):

### You need to cast your dice to a sequence

The trick for dealing with a roll of dice as individual rolls (and not their sum) is to cast it into a sequence. For this, we use a function and specify our dice parameter as a sequence (appending `:s`). Once we have it as a sequence, we can compare each value to a number. That will give the number of elements in the sequence for which the comparison is true.

```
function: number of A:s greater or eq than T:n {
   result: A >= T
}

output [number of 5d6 greater or eq than 1d10]
```

Comment: Actually, in this case [there's a way to do it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181304) without using a sequence parameter. But the method you describe is indeed very powerful and useful in cases where faster methods won't work, so have a +1.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [probably the fastest way to do it](https://anydice.com/program/20c53):

```
function: test T:n {
  X: d6 >= T
  result: 5dX
}
output [test d10]
```

The first trick used here is that, when a die (here, a `d10`) is passed to a function expecting a number (i.e. as a parameter tagged with `:n`), AnyDice will automatically call the function for every possible sum of the roll and calculate a weighted average of the results.  Thus, inside the function the roll is effectively "frozen" and can be treated as a fixed number.

Next, I use the expression `d6 >= T` to obtain a distribution that equals 1 with probability \$(7-T) \mathbin/ 6\$ (i.e. the probability of rolling at least `T` on a d6) and 0 otherwise, and save it as a custom die in the variable `X`.  And then I roll 5 of these custom dice to get the number of rolls exceeding `T` on 5d6 and return it.

Of course, if you want to make the function more flexible, you could also pass the die to be rolled and/or the number of dice in the pool as additional parameters to it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
function: csuccess roll ROLL:s with target TARGET:n {
  if TARGET < 7 {
    result: [count {TARGET..6} in ROLL]
  }
  else {
    result: 0
  }
}

output [csuccess roll 5d6 with target 1d10]
```

For a better understanding of what this is doing, this is a less efficient method of the exact same solution:

```
function: csuccess roll ROLL:s with target TARGET:n {
  NUMONES: [count {1} in ROLL]
  NUMTWOS: [count {2} in ROLL]
  NUMTHREES: [count {3} in ROLL]
  NUMFOURS: [count {4} in ROLL]
  NUMFIVES: [count {5} in ROLL]
  NUMSIXES: [count {6} in ROLL]

  if TARGET = 1 {
    result: NUMONES+NUMTWOS+NUMTHREES+NUMFOURS+NUMFIVES+NUMSIXES
  }
  if TARGET = 2 {
    result: NUMTWOS+NUMTHREES+NUMFOURS+NUMFIVES+NUMSIXES
  }
  if TARGET = 3 {
    result: NUMTHREES+NUMFOURS+NUMFIVES+NUMSIXES
  }
  if TARGET = 4 {
    result: NUMFOURS+NUMFIVES+NUMSIXES
  }
  if TARGET = 5 {
    result: NUMFIVES+NUMSIXES
  }
  if TARGET = 6 {
    result: NUMSIXES
  }
  result: 0
}

output [csuccess roll 5d6 with target 1d10]
```

Comment: It's strange that there are more odds of getting 5 successes than 1,2,3 or 4.... And how getting 1,2,3 or 4 sucesses are nearly equal... P.S. I'm not the one who downvoted. On the contrary, thanks a lot for trying to help!

Comment: @DaniCano That is correct, though. There is a 100% chance of rolling 5 successes if a 1 is rolled. There is a 0% chance of rolling 1,2,3 or 4 successes if a 1 is rolled. This immediately adds +0.1 to the probability of rolling a 5 (because there is a 0.1 chance that you will roll a 1 on 1d10).

Comment: Yeah, you're right... What if we assume the zero on the d10 is zero and not 10?

Comment: Then, in my first solution, change 'output [csuccess roll 5d6 with success 1d10]' to 'output [csuccess roll 5d6 with success d{0..9}]'

Comment: @InterstellarProbe is there a reason your function is casting the TARGET parameter as a sequence (:s) rather than a number (:n)? (When only rolling one die to determine the target number it works either way, anyway.)

Comment: I did not realize that! I am fairly new to Anydice programming. I just started yesterday. I edited my response. Thanks :)